# Is it possible to get a file that is in storage disk - "local"?

Tags: laravel

please tell me. My version is Laravel 5.2.

config/filesystems.php configuration:

```php
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
],

'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

If I save the file this way:

```php
Storage::disk('local')->put('token/token.json', json_encode($data));
```

Will users be able to access it? I just need to keep the token in a safe place so that no one can access it. Thank you in advance for your response

Comment: So, you need to secure your local storage from external user, right? CMIIW, hope it works for you https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-upload-file-and-hide-real-url-for-secure-download-under-uuid/

Comment: @Aulia Wiguna Thanks, yes. I wanted to make sure that if I save the file to - "storage / app / token / token.json", users cannot access this file.